# Using FlatList and react-native-table-component components will cause the entire page to render slowly

Tags: react-native

Using FlatList and react-native-table-component components will cause the entire page to render slowly, for example: when I click a button to change the button color, the rendering is very slow, but if I comment the loop code in the picture, it will return to normal Rendering, how to solve this problem

```js
<Table style={{ marginTop: 10, }}>
  <FlatList
    data={dateRows}
    initialNumToRender={4}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
</Table>
```

```js
_renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  const element = (data, col, temp, index) => (
    col == 1 && index != 7 ?
      <Button style={[styles.timeStyle, styles.available]} onPress=
        {() => this.toBook(temp, index, col)}>
        <Text style={styles.descText}>{data}</Text>
      </Button> : index != 7 && col == 2 ?
        <Button style={[styles.timeStyle]} >
          Text style={[styles.descText, styles.bookedText]}>{data}</Text>
     </Button > : index != 7 ?
    <Button style={styles.timeStyle} >
      <Text style={[styles.descText, styles.bookedText]}>{data}</Text>
    </Button> : null

  );
  return <TableWrapper key={index} style={styles.row}>
    {
      item.data.map((cellData, cellIndex) => (
        <Cell key={cellIndex} data={element(item.time, item.data[cellIndex], item, cellIndex)} style={{ width: 120, marginBottom: 10, }} textStyle={styles.text} />
      ))
    }
  </TableWrapper>
}
```